# Solve this probability problem symbolically

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, geometry

> Consider a unit square, Pick two points P and Q uniformly at random
>   inside the square, What is the probability that |PQ|>1?

I tried solve this problem

```
Integrate[Boole[(x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2>1],{x1,0,1},{y1,0,1},{x2,0,1},{y2,0,1}]
```

above code with `NIntegrate` given `0.025074` , but I want a symbolically result as except is $\frac{19}{6}-\pi$ .

Comment: To show that the numeric result is equivalent to the analytic result: `(NIntegrate[Boole[(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 > 1], {x1, 0, 1}, {y1, 0, 1}, {x2, 0, 1}, {y2, 0, 1}] + Pi // RootApproximant) - Pi` evaluates to `19/6 - Pi`

Comment: @mathe thank you for accepting my answer. However, I think the other answers are more instructive and efficient, e.g. wolfies

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not quick (includes J.M. comment):

```
pdf = UniformDistribution[2];
td = TransformedDistribution[(x - y)^2, {x, y} \[Distributed] pdf];
zd = TransformedDistribution[
   a + b, {a \[Distributed] td, b \[Distributed] td}];
```

then

```
ans = 1 - FullSimplify[CDF[zd,1]]
```

yields the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Could also try `Probability[
 EuclideanDistance[{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}] < 
  1, {{x1, y1} \[Distributed] pdf, {x2, y2} \[Distributed] pdf}]` but it's taking a fair while too... (also I think `z` should be `zd` in your `CDF`)

Comment: You could use `pdf = UniformDistribution[2]` for short.

Comment: @J.M. thank you (as always for feedback). The other answers are much more instructive and I have commented to OP the same.  I felt guilty so: https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/not-seeing-the-triangles-for-the-squares/

Answer (score 14):

This is an interesting problem, because the difficulty is not the concept, but rather how to compute it (efficiently). Given points $(X_i,Y_i)$ distributed Uniformly on the unit square, we are interested in $$P\big[\sqrt{(X_2-X_1)^2 + (Y_2-Y_1)^2} \; > \; 1\big] $$

Let $X = X_2 - X_1$ denote the difference of two standard Uniform random variables, which is well-known to be a symmetric Triangular distribution on (-1,1). Similarly, let $Y = Y_2-Y_1$. By independence, the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$, say $f(x,y)$ is then:

```
       f = (1-Abs[x]) (1-Abs[y]);       domain[f] = {{x,-1,1}, {y,-1,1}};
```

We seek:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/probinthesquare3.png))</sub>

All done. This takes just 2 seconds to evaluate, starting from a fresh kernel, where I am using the `Prob` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* (how I roll, being one of the authors), but one can equally use in-built *Mathematica* functions to the same effect:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(1 - Abs[x]) (1 - Abs[y]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]; 
Probability[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 1, Distributed[{x, y}, dist]]
```

Comment: Well. two seconds and, say, US$ 127

Comment: How much did you pay for your copy of _Mathematica_?

Comment: As I  noted above, one can follow the same approach with built-in functions. Here is some code to do that: `dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(1 - Abs[x]) (1 - Abs[y]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];    Probability[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 1, Distributed[{x, y}, dist]]`

Comment: @woflies Nice! Do you mind adding it to your answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: Sure. The point was never meant to be about actual code - but the conceptual approach, which works nicely either way here.

Answer (score 13):

What's with all the heavy lifting and machinations?

```
d = ProductDistribution[{TriangularDistribution[{-1, 1}], 2}];
Probability[a^2 + b^2 > 1, {a, b} \[Distributed] d]
```

> $\frac{19}{6}-\pi$

Finishes in a few seconds on a *netbook*...

Comment: After some testing of my own, that makes *two* netbooks. :)

Comment: Looks like Wolfram could improve it code by replacing the difference of two uniforms by a triangular. The computation is much faster.

Comment: @ciao when I looked on my phone I didn't see who posted this...but I am not surprised...I expiated my sins :https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/not-seeing-the-triangles-for-the-squares/ , and suggested OP look at all the other nicer answers...:)

Comment: @ubpdqn - LOL - don't post here as much, busy herding a startup. Nice blog - I actually ran across it in the past (came up in a G-Search result), had it bookmarked as a cool place. Did not know it was you until now... though had I paid attention to the address it would have been obvious.

Comment: @ciao best wishes for start up...blog is meaningless musings...play.  Have fun :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a "please don't reinvent the wheel" type of answer. From Michael Trott, [**here**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComputationalGeometry/SquareLinePicking.nb)

```
p[l_] := Piecewise[{
   {2 l (l^2 - 4 l + π), 0 <= l <= 1}, 
   {2 l (4 Sqrt[l^2 - 1] - (l^2 + 2 - π) - 4 ArcTan[Sqrt[l^2 - 1]]), 1 < l <= Sqrt[2]}}]

With[{n = 1}, Integrate[ p[l], {l, 1, Sqrt@2}]] // Simplify

(* 19/6 - π *)
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem can also be solved in a generalized form.
What is the probability that the distance between the two points is greater than t ?

The PDF for the distance of two random variables equally distributed between 0 and 1 is

```
f[u_] := 1 - u Sign[u]
```

Hence the probability in question is

```
p[t_] = Integrate[f[u] f[v] Boole[u^2 + v^2 > t^2], {v, -1, 1}, {u, -1, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> t > 0] // Simplify
```

(* Because Latex has unfavorable line breaks I write down the Mathematica expressions for the two regions of t *)

```
Simplify[p[t], 0 < t < 1]

(* Out[230]= 1 - π t^2 + (8 t^3)/3 - t^4/2 *)

Simplify[p[t], 1 < t < Sqrt[2]]

(* Out[231]= 1/12 (8 + 24 t^2 - 3 π t^2 + 6 t^4 - 
   16 Sqrt[-1 + t^2] - 32 t^2 Sqrt[-1 + t^2] - 18 t^2 ArcCsc[t] + 
   30 t^2 ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 + t^2]]) *)
```

(* Here's Latex *)

$$ 
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{t^4}{2}+\frac{8 t^3}{3}-\pi  t^2+1 & 0<t\leq 1 \\
 \frac{1}{12} \left(6 t^4-32 \sqrt{t^2-1} t^2-3 \pi  t^2+24 t^2-16\sqrt{t^2-1}+30 t^2 \tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{t^2-1}\right)-18 t^2 \csc^{-1}(t)+8\right)& 1<t<\sqrt{2} \\
\end{array}
$$

We recover

```
p[1]

(* Out[222]= 19/6 - π *)
```

The graph of `p[t]` is

```
Plot[p[t], {t, 0, Sqrt[2]}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "p(t)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Probability that the distance between two points\nrandomly chosen in the \
unit square is greater than t"]
```

[image]

Comment: another nice answer +. I felt so guilty with little effort I had to : https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/not-seeing-the-triangles-for-the-squares/

Comment: @ubpdqn  Thanks for the hint to your beautiful page. BTW I started to study the same question for the unit circle, but haven't yet found an analytic solution.

Comment: Why not post that as an interesting question here ...

Comment: @wolfies Thanks for the suggestion. Done.